# I have 100's of xml files in source folder, I want to move those files to 3 different destination folders using python

Tags: python-3.x

"I have Hundreds of xml files in source folder, I want to move those files to 3 different destination folders using python."

Comment: The  Python `os` library has stuff for this. The more challenging part is, how do you know which file will go to which folder? E.g. is it by name, or size or ...?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you currently stuck?

Comment: Randomly I want to move files from source to 3 desination folders

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move them randomly, you can use code below.
You can use more destinations, just add them to destinations list.

```
import glob
import random
import shutil

source = "source_folder"
destinations = ["destination_folder1", "destination_folder2", "destination_folder3"]

files = glob.iglob(f"{source}\\*.xml")
for file in files:
    random_destination = destinations[random.randint(0, len(destinations) - 1)]
    shutil.move(file, random_destination)
    print(f"File '{file}' was moved to '{random_destination}'.")
```